# CentOS Apache HTTPD Configuration (403 Forbidden)

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd, http-status-code-403

This is what i have in my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin spero78@spero78.com
        ServerName mcmoddr.com
        ServerAlias www.mcmoddr.com
        DocumentRoot /home/mcmoddr/www/
        ErrorLog /mcmoddr/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /mcmoddr/logs/accesslog combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When visiting thwe site i get a 403 Forbidden error, The files are added with vsftpd and have the permissions drwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 13):

You are using a stock install of CentOS, if that is correct please check that
 if SELinux is in Enforcing mode

```
getenforce
```

if the result is "Enforcing"

temporally change it to permissive

```
setenforce 0
```

and try again, you can also guide the condition of web content to the files in your home directory.

Comment: This did the trick in my case. But if I subsequently reinforce again (with **setenforce 1**) the 403 error doesn't show up anymore, even though the configuration is the same as before, when it used to show up.

Comment: this is nothing more than a dirty hack. Its certainly not the proper way to simply disable security features. You should configure them instead.

Answer (score 9):

**Disable SELinux or run in ROOT**

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /home/
```

Answer (score 5):

Freaktor's answer of 'setenforce 0' did "work" for me (thanks!)

But to keep it working and re-enable SELinux, I needed to

```
sudo chcon -Rv --type=httpd_t /path/to/my/files
```

...this gave my directory and all files and directories within it the security context of "httpd_t" which is a clunky way of saying SELinux let httpd read those files.

enabling selinux again was as simple as

```
setenforce 1
```

Comment: This is just temporary; any new files you make would have their original context and SELinux would still deny access to the new files. For a permanent solution, see [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/409488/126632).

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a deny all somewhere in the global config. Try adding this to the vhost stanza:

```
<Directory /home/mcmoddr/www>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: +1, Also @Spero78 should make sure no .htaccess file is in root of your vhost with restrictive directives

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below line in your existing code.

```
restorecon -r /home/mcmoddr/www/
```

It should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the **`<Directory>`** container as it mentioned above .

And then you need to check from your **`DocumentRoot`** path, Each directory must have read permission so the service user **apache** can access .

you can check using **`ls -ld`**